# after putting wrong credentials my login form redirects the user to wp_login form on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms-authentication, login-page, error-messaging

I have created login page for users of my web site. It redirects users to another page of that web site. For this purposes I have used wp_login form from wordpress. Although after putting wrong credentials it redirects me to wp-login.php and shows there error message. I tried some codes, but they were still that redirection was happening. How can I fix it. Any help, please?

('url'),
        'form_id' => 'sign-in',
        'label_log_in' => ( 'Sign in' ),

```
'echo'           => true,
    'remember'       => true,
    'form_id'        => 'loginform',
    'id_username'    => 'user_login',
    'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username or Email Address' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),

    'value_username' => '',
    'value_remember' => false


      ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail' );  // hook failed login

function my_front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
   $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
   // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
   if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
  wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );  // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
  exit;
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and still it redirects me to wp_login form. Maybe I do smth wrong?